# libreoffice-convert not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, libreoffice

So, I am using the [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert), running in my nodejs application of course.
My code as below

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(enterPath);
// Convert it to pdf format with undefined filter (see Libreoffice doc about filter)
libre.convert(file, extend, undefined, (err, done) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error converting file: ${err}`);
    }
    
    // Here in done you have pdf file which you can save or transfer in another stream
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, done);
});
```

The code above returns an error when it tries to open LibreOffice.

```
The application cannot be started. 
The configuration file "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\bootstrap.ini" is corrupt.
```

This is the content of my `bootstrap.ini`

```
[Bootstrap]
InstallMode=<installmode>
ProductKey=LibreOffice 7.0
UserInstallation=$SYSUSERCONFIG/LibreOffice/4
```

Really appreciate if anyone could help to solve this. Also not sure if it helps, but I am running it on Windows.

Comment: Can you run `soffice.exe` from `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program`? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I can run the `soffice.exe`. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: And `bootstrap.ini` looks good too?

Comment: Ahh yes, I have updated the question and included the content of my `bootstrap.ini`.

Comment: @Anatoly, it was pretty straightforward on Mac, after installing LibreOffice and everything works fine. But on Windows, THIS happened.

Comment: You can add console.log(results.soffice, command) to 'node_modules\libreoffice-convert\index.js' before the line `return exec(command, callback)` and try to execute this command manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if someone is facing the same issue as I did, here's what I did to solve it.

1. Download and install the LibreOffice. You can download it [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/)

2. After running `npm i libreoffice-convert`, go to `your_project/node_modules/libreoffice-convert/index.js`, find the code below.

```
/* your_project/node_modules/libreoffice-convert/index.js */

let command = `-env:UserInstallation=file://${installDir.name} --headless --convert-to ${format}`;

// change to 

let command = `${installDir.name} --headless --convert-to ${format}`;
```

3. Try your script now.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following change in libreoffice-convert/index.js

```
// change

let command = `${results.soffice} -env:UserInstallation=file://${installDir.name} --headless --convert-to ${format}`;

// to

let command = `${results.soffice}  --headless --convert-to ${format}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in `libreoffice-convert` and it is still in the `Open` state: [issue](https://github.com/elwerene/libreoffice-convert/issues/32). You can try a workaround from the discussion in this issue comments

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Install: `yum install libreoffice-headless`

[Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/625890/how-to-fix-x11-error-cant-open-display)